# How better this can be written? PHP code

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to generate final string to show users based on some conditions.

```
$flag=0;
$var='Please ';
if($user->is_details_updated == 'N' && $user->needs_to_update_details == "Y")
{
    $var='update your profile details';
    $flag=1;
}
if ($flag ==1)
{
    $var=' and ';
}
if($user->is_pass_changed == 'N' && $user->needs_to_update_password == "Y")
{   
    $var.='change password';
}
```

So, If all three `if` return `true` then final `$var` looks like this:

> Please update your profile details and change password

How this can be written better?

Comment: You can post this on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) - another StackExchange page, this question fits there more than here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add messages to array and then join them with `and`

```
$var = arrray()
if($user->is_details_updated == 'N' && $user->needs_to_update_details == "Y")
{
    $var[] ='update your profile details';

}

if($user->is_pass_changed == 'N' && $user->needs_to_update_password == "Y")
{   
    $var[]='change password';
}

echo join(" and ", $var);
```

Comment: Damn, just beaten to it... +1 :).

Comment: @skowron-line Instead of "U", please start using "you" on Stack Overflow. "Chat speak" is specifically disallowed here.

Comment: @meagar sorry about that im used to write like this. But will change it

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
$sayings = array();

if($user->is_details_updated == 'N' && $user->needs_to_update_details == "Y") {
    $sayings[] = 'update your profile details';
}

if($user->is_pass_changed == 'N' && $user->needs_to_update_password == "Y") {   
    $sayings[] = 'change password';
}

$var = 'Please ' . implode(' and ', $sayings);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion would be (if possible) to refactor the `$user->is_details_updated`, `$user->needs_to_update_details`, `$user->is_pass_changed`, `$user->needs_to_update_password` properties to return boolean `true`/`false` values.  This might save some debugging headaches later on.